# tb mega menu is not showing in bootrap theams in drupal7

Tags: routes

I am new user of drupal 7.3. I am using bootstrap 3.0 theme in drupal 7.3.

I am using [tb mega menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/tb_megamenu) which is not showing. Black color box will be occurred in navigation block.

Please help me to solve this I want solution step by step. I want used in my project please help me.

Comment: https://groups.drupal.org/node/301648

Answer (score 0):

I have refer you to below links :

1. [LINK1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnuhbFwsJ3M)
2. [LINK2](http://www.themebrain.com/guide/tb-mega-menu-quick-guide)
3. [LINK3](https://www.gaslampmedia.com/tutorial-drupal-mega-menu-with-bootstrap-3-x-and-jquery/)

Comment: Compile the LESS files

Compile the LESS files to create your style.css, which contains all of the Bootstrap CSS , Drupal-specific overrides (overrides.less), and your own custom code.

lessc less/style.less > css/style.css

this is solution of tb mega menu problem .but actually i don't know how to compile this file.please help me

Comment: Compile the LESS files .Compile the LESS files to create your style.css, which contains all of the Bootstrap CSS , Drupal-specific overrides (overrides.less), and your own custom code.lessc less/style.less > css/style.css.how to solve this step i don't know.plese help me